# Is Swagger UI like a sandbox? How does Swagger UI work

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to understand how Swagger UI works and what kind of scenario it suits for. 
Per my understanding, it's not a sandbox when integrating with Swagger UI. That means Swagger UI manipulates real data. Is that correct?

So usually I have to build a dedicated test environment for Swagger UI, right? Sounds not right to me. 
Even there is a test environment for Swagger UI, since it's open to lots of people. Does that mean the dummy data posted by someone will be saved forever and visible to others?

I was expecting Swagger UI behaves like a sandbox which only saves and manipulate the data for the current session. Once the user closes the session then re-open it, it should be brand-new.

I would like to know the typical scenario in which Swagger UI is used.

Comment: "Swagger" is not a single tool but a collective name for a [family of tools](https://swagger.io/tools/), including Swagger Editor, Swagger UI (API documentation renderer), Swagger Codegen (code generator), Swagger Parser (OpenAPI document parser), Swagger Inflector, and others. There are also other [open-source projects](https://swagger.io/tools/open-source/open-source-integrations/) built around the OpenAPI Specification that use "Swagger" in their name but are not actually part of SmartBear's Swagger toolset. Which exactly tool/project do you mean?

Comment: @Helen Thanks for the reminding. I mean Swagger UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the name, isn't it? It generates a UI for your API.

It does not spin up a demo environment for your API with the accompanying back-end, including a test database that contains dummy data and/or is periodically wiped.

If you want the latter, you'd have to build that your own.

> Does that mean the dummy data posted by someone will be saved forever and visible to others?

Given that your API uses authentication, you will need authentication in order for Swagger UI to make calls. If you do not separate authenticated users' data, then that's a problem in your API, not a problem of Swagger.

Consider that Swagger UI presents you with a visual way to call your API. Anything you can do with Swagger, you can do with any REST/HTTP client, and so can your potential consumers.

Comment: Thank you. I missed the "authentication" part